# Motion of a plank hinged about a point

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

There is a plank hinged about a point O. At the free end of the plank a small impulse is given.  Will the plank perform pure rotation or both rotation and translation?

Comment: how can it translate if it is hinged? Isn't the hinge fixed to a wall or something? Are you talking about the center of mass? How do you push it, sideways, at an angle? Is the hinge in a plane? This question is vague. Generally a free plank will both translate or rotate when pushed, but a hinged plack will only rotate around the hinge. Whether you consider that translation depends on whether you are considering the center of mass motion or the hinge point motion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both Rotation and Translation. It will execute neither pure rotation nor pure translation

Comment: While this is formally correct it comes without explanation of how it was arrived at at does not improve on Ron's comment.